# Fixing Register Spilling in Your Program

Tags: performance, optimization, compiler-construction, cpu-registers

I see through CLANG's optimization report that my hot loop has register spills in `regalloc` pass. Are there any general programming techniques on how to avoid the spills, or how to suggest the compiler what variable to prefer to spill. I was looking online, but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: If you show the code people might have some ideas on how to reduce its complexity.

Answer (score 1):

In C and C++, the **`register` keyword** is specifically designed for that:

> `register`: automatic storage duration. Also hints to the compiler to place the object in the processor's register.

That being said, it is now obsolete and unused since C++17 (still used in C though). [Here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/storage_duration) is the documentation about that in C, and [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) for C++.

AFAIK, modern compilers tend to simply ignore this keyword since they tends to do a very very good job. Even when they fail, a register spilling is not so critical on modern x64 mainstream processors having 16 general purpose registers and generally at least 2 load units (recent ones also tends to have two store units). That being said, this can still be an issue for embedded processors and in some very critical loops.

One solution is simply to **avoid using many variables in critical loops** and reduce their scope as much as possible (though optimizing compilers should be able to reorder instructions very well nowadays). For this reason, it can sometime be beneficial to to **split loops in two or more** so to reduce the register pressure. This method is especially useful on modern processor where basic loops have a relatively small overhead thanks to the instruction-level parallelism and out-of-order execution. When a register tiling optimization is performed, the tile size must be carefully tuned for the target architecture so to avoid register spilling which can actually completely defeat the optimization.  In some desperate situations or in very critical loops, a solution is simply to **write the code is assembler directly**. AFAIK, some projects like Openh264 (fast video decoding) GOTO BLAS (fast basic linear algebra) does that.